# displaying mapped images in jsx react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am using Material UI's Carousel Component, in attempt to display my image. The carousel is working fine, but the images are not showing... just an image file picture which lets me know, that it is aware a picture is supposed to be showing. When I put the file directly inline, the image shows up fine:
(`<img src={akira}/>`),

but not when mapped.

Am i doing something wrong with my code?

```
import React from 'react';
import Carousel from 'react-material-ui-carousel';
import {Paper} from '@material-ui/core'
import akira from './images/akira.jpg';
import hunter from './images/hunter.jpg';
import kiki from './images/kiki.jpg';
import middle from './images/middle.jpg';
import './Header.css';

function Header()
{    
    var items = [
        {
            image: akira
        },
        {
            image: hunter
        },
        {
            image: kiki
        },
        {
            image: middle
        }
    ]
 
    return (
        <div className="header">
            <Carousel>
                {
                    items.map( (i, image) => <Item key={i} items={image} alt='image'/> )
                    
                }
            </Carousel>
        </div>
    )
}
 
function Item(props)
{
    return (

        <Paper>
            <img src={props.items}/>
            <p>{props.alt}</p>
        </Paper>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: 1. in the callback passed to [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax), the first argument is the element, the index is the second 2. your first element is `{ image: akira }`, not `akira`, so you need `.map((item, i) => <Item key={i} items={item.image} ... />)` (3. don't call the attribute `items` when it's actually a single image)

Comment: To debug code like this, you can insert `<pre>{JSON.stringify(props)}</pre>` in your Item component's JSX.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

1. in the map function image is `index` value and interchange arg parameter then `image` the object so we need to access `image.image`
2. use `index` for key props

```js
function Header() {
  var items = [
    {
      image: akira,
    },
    {
      image: hunter,
    },
    {
      image: kiki,
    },
    {
      image: middle,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="header">
      <Carousel>
        {items.map((item, idx) => (
          <Item key={idx} items={item.image} alt="image" />
        ))}
      </Carousel>
    </div>
  );
}

function Item(props) {
  return (
    <Paper>
      <img src={props.items} />
      <p>{props.alt}</p>
    </Paper>
  );
}

export default Header;
```